# Django use edit form as add user gives error

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I'm using **Django 2.2.x**.

I want to use all fields which are in the edit user form to the add user form.
For that I have extended **AuthUserAdmin**

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):

    inlines = [
        ProfileAdminInline
    ]

    fieldsets = AuthUserAdmin.fieldsets
    add_fieldsets = AuthUserAdmin.fieldsets

    list_filter = [
        'is_staff',
        'is_active',
        'is_superuser',
        'last_login',
        'date_joined',
    ]

    list_display = [
        'email',
        'full_name',
        'is_staff',
        'is_superuser',
        'is_active',
        'last_login',
        'date_joined',
    ]

    ordering = ('-date_joined', 'username',)

    search_fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

But adding user gives error

```
Please correct the errors below
```

But no field is highlighted for the error.

**How can I use edit form as add form in Django admin add user?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_fieldsets` includes `password1` and `password2`.

```
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
```

So you can't replace it with `fieldsets`, which has `password`.

```
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        ...
```

You could try combining them as follows:

```
    # You can remove 'fieldsets' since it will 
    # inherit AuthUserAdmin.fieldsets by default
    fieldsets = AuthUserAdmin.fieldsets
    add_fieldsets = AuthUserAdmin.add_fieldsets + AuthUserAdmin.fieldsets[1:]
```

That will solve the error, but I don't think it will work, because the user admin has:

```
add_form = UserCreationForm
```

You'll need to create a custom form with the extra fields you want.